# Non-blocking custom errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Consider such example:

```
function Object(param) {
   if(param == null) throw new Error('custom error');
   return param;
}

var obj1 = new Object(1);
var obj2 = new Object();
var obj3 = new Object(3);
```

obj2 will block execution of whole script. Is it possible to block execution of only that particular object? If I do this:

```
function Object(param) {
   if(param == null) console.log(new Error('custom error'));
   return param;
}
```

It will execute console.log 3 times instead of log string once which is also undesired effect. Second code is non blocking but it's not error anymore.

EDIT: https://github.com/wisniewski94/sprites.js/blob/master/sprite.js

rangeErr as an example

EDIT2: turns out that if you set console.log in variable it will always call that log even without using this variable.

```
function Object(param) {
   var err = console.log(new Error('custom error'))
   if(param == null) err;
   return param;
}
```

Comment: if you throw an error. catch the error. The position you catch the error defines the program logic and what is executed and what is not.

Comment: _It will execute console.log 3 times instead of log string once which is also undesired effect._ this should not happen with the code you showed us! It should be logged only once as you expected

Comment: As far as "it's not error anymore", if you want something to show as an error in console, you can use `console.error`.

Comment: @BrettZamir this is good hint thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaK just checked in jsbin and you must be right. Sounds like there are mor errors in my code. I will post it on github in a second.
EDIT: posted

Comment: @JoshuaK well, seems like if I set variable with console.log it will console always even without calling that variable. That's why code doesn't match question.

Comment: `console.log` is not returning the argument. So can not do what you try. you have to write it the other way: `console.log(variable = value);`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using console.error() for throwing custom errors and simple return; for blocking execution of function.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
function object(param) {
    if (param == null) {
        console.log(new Error('custom error'));
    }
    return param;
}
```

you can replace `console.log` with `console.error` too

also you should be careful with javascript's reserved keywords `Object` (with an uppercase O) is one of them (well not really a keyword but a really important object)